# How to add new options to selection menu on editable TextField?

Tags: textfield, android-jetpack-compose

I have an editable TextField. When doing a selection on the text, I have the following menu: Copy, Paste, Cut, Select All. I want to add some additional items to this menu. How can I do that with Android jetpack compose?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. There is a related [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218266808). Please vote for it to attract Google's attention.